# Is there a place where all filesystems supported by Debian are listed?

Tags: linux, debian, filesystems

I looked at https://wiki.debian.org/FileSystem and ran

```
[$] find /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/fs/
```

There seems to be a bit of difference between the ones listed on the page and the ones which are generated by the query.

While https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems does share some of the filesystems but not in the same depth. Can somebody help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two lists (from the kernel and the wiki page) are actually quite similar (on a 4.8 kernel). The differences I see are as follows:

- listed on the wiki, absent from the kernel:

  - `ext2`, `ext3`, `ext4dev` — subsumed into `ext4`
  - `kafs` — now simply `afs`
  - `autofs` — obsolete
  - `cramfs` — obsolete
  - `hpfs` — disabled in Debian since 2.6.38
  - `jbd` — obsolete
- listed in the kernel, absent from the wiki:

  - `cachefiles` — caching filesystem
  - `ceph` — Ceph distributed filesystem
  - `efivarfs` — filesystem providing access to EFI variables
  - `exofs` — OSD storage
  - `f2fs` — [F2FS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F2FS)
  - `fscache` — general filesystem caching manager
  - `logfs` — experimental LogFS
  - `nilfs2` — [NILFS2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NILFS)
  - `overlayfs` — overlay filesystem support
  - `qnx6` — QNX 6 filesystem
  - `squashfs` — SquashFS
  - `crypto` — per-file encryption

To answer your actual question, the wiki page you found is the place, it just needs updating. The definitive list for any given kernel version is the filesystems supported by that kernel.

In addition to this, as pointed out by [plugwash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/122182/plugwash), Debian also supports filesystems *via* FUSE drivers or out-of-tree kernel modules. To find these, look for `fuse` and `dkms`'s reverse-dependencies; among them:

- `ntfs-3g` (read/write support for NTFS)
- `exfat-fuse` (exFAT)
- `glusterfs-client` (Gluster)
- `mtpfs` (MTP)
- `zfs-fuse` and `zfs-dkms` (ZFS)
- `aufs-dkms` (AUFS)
- `openafs-modules-dkms` (OpenAFS)

Comment: Well that is the definitive list for filesystems supported by in-tree modules in that kernel, a filesystem could also be supported by a driver in another package (either a fuse based driver or an out-of-tree module)

Comment: Thanks @plugwash, I've added some of those to the list. (I need to update the wiki page...)